# Populate environment variables from OpenShift secret with Docker build strategy

Tags: openshift

I would like to use on opaque OpenShift secret inside a build pod as environment variable. The secret contains three key-value pairs, so they should become available as three environment variables. (This is for OpenShift 3.9).

I have found a [documented example](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/secrets.html) for OpenShift's Source build strategy (`sourceStrategy`), but need this in the context of a build configuration with Docker build strategy (`dockerStrategy`). `oc explain` suggests that extraction of secrets into environment variables should work with both build strategies. So far, so good:

```
oc explain bc.spec.strategy.sourceStrategy.env.valueFrom.secretKeyRef
oc explain bc.spec.strategy.dockerStrategy.env.valueFrom.secretKeyRef
```

My build configuration is created from a template, so I have added a section like this as a sibling of `dockerStragegy` where the template refers to the build configuration:

```
  env:
  - name: SECRET_1
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: my-secret
        key: role-1
  - name: SECRET_2
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: my-secret
        key: role-2
  - name: SECRET_3
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: my-secret
        key: role-3
```

The secret was created like this:

```
oc create secret generic my-secret \
  --from-literal=role-1=... --from-literal=role-2=... --from-literal=role-3=...
```

After uploading the new template (with `oc replace`) and recreating the application and hence the build configuration from it (with `oc new-app`) I observe the following:

- The template contains `env` as expected (checked with `oc get template -o yaml`).
- The build configuration does not contain the desired `env` (checked with `oc get bc -o yaml`).

What could be the reason why and am I correct in assuming that secrets can be made available inside environment variables for the Docker build strategy. For context: my Dockerfile sets up a relational database (in its `ENTRYPOINT` script), and needs to configure passwords for three roles, and these should stem from the secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my mistake: `env` should reside as a child (not sibling) of `dockerStrategy` inside the template (as had already been suggested by `oc explain`'s cited path). I've now fixed this, and so the desired parts now show up both in the template and in the build configuration.